# Я не могу понять почему у меня list index out of range

Tags: python

```
def sr(a_2, l):
    for o in range(l):
        if a_2[o] < 0 or a_2[o] % 2 != 0:
            a_2.pop(o)
    print(a_2)
    sm = 0
    for v in a_2:
        sm = sm + v
    res = sm / l
    return res


a_1 = []
n = int(input("Кол-во элементов = "))

for i in range(n):
    y = float(input("Элемент {} = ".format(i)))
    a_1.append(y)
print(a_1)


fin = sr(a_1, len(a_1))
print("Результат: {}".format(fin))
```

Comment: одни и те же грабли у людей - НЕЛЬЗЯ УДАЛЯТЬ ЭЛЕМЕНТЫ СПИСКА ПОКА ВЫ ДВИГАЕТЕСЬ ПО ЭТОМУ СПИСКУ

Comment: @Zhihar если видите такие вопрос, то пожалуйста закрывайте их как дубликат

Comment: @Danis, ну я бы не назвал это дубликатом - все таки коды разные, но ошибка общая

Comment: Для вас самый лучший вариант - создание нового списка без тех елементов, которые ты удаляешь. Иначе получаешь ошибку от питона